# Admob in Fragment with gridview

Tags: android, admob

I want to put a banner in the same fragment container a gridview, like an activity in top side.

How can i add a Admob banner in a fragment contain gridview, recommendations? i want a best practice answer for this case. Thanks!

Comment: Just add a layout to the gridview, and assign the admob to that layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here TextView can be replaced by your AdView.